# How to find record from an array of two dimensional array in rails 3?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, multidimensional-array

I am working on Rails 3.0. I have a two dimensional array. The two dimensional array consists of user data and a boolean value.

For example: `[ [user1,true], [user2,true], [user3,false] ]`

It looks something like this:

```
[
    [#<User id: 1, email: "abc@abc.com", username: "abc">, true],
    [#<User id: 2, email: "ijk@ijk.com", username: "ijk">, true],
    [#<User id: 3, email: "xyz@xyz.com", username: "xyz">, false],
]
```

I want to find/extract records conditionally; say finding an entire row where `User id=2`, it should return only the second row i.e. `[#<User id: 2, email: "ijk@ijk.com", username: "ijk">, true]`

Is there anyway to loop through such arrays? How can it be achieved?

Comment: It is a simple loop; what have you tried so far? As an aside, do you want to do this only with an in-memory array or is your goal to be efficient and load only that record from the database?

Comment: it should efficiently fetch only one record.. I'm checking the following solutions...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
my_array.select{ |user, flag| user.id == 2}
```

all users with true flag:

```
my_array.select{ |user, flag| flag }
```

or false:

```
my_array.select{ |user, flag| !flag }
```

Comment: I'm new to this, but surprisingly when I tried first command `@m.select{ |user, flag| user.id == 2}` it returned all the three records. So instead of `select` I used `detect` and it worked. The other two commands `@m.select{ |user, flag| flag }` and `@m.select{ |user, flag| !flag }` worked very well. Thanks...

Comment: looks like you try `@m.select{ |user, flag| user.id = 2}` or all off them are with ID=2

Answer (score 11):

You can do something like

```
[ [user1,true], [user2,true], [user3,false] ].select { |u| u.first.id == 2}
```

This will return only the records that have the user id equal to 2.

Comment: `@m.select{ |u| u.first.id == 2 }` returning all the records. But when I changed it to `@m.detect{ |u| u.first.id == 2 }` it returned only one record. I'm new to it. Can you tell me why it is so?

Answer (score 9):

Same answer as @eugen, only syntax difference(and using detect to return single dimensional array instead of 2 dimensional array):

```
[ [user1,true], [user2,true], [user3,false] ].detect { |user, boolean| user.id == 2 }
=> [user2, true]
```